# Keras Model.predict returns the error 'Matrix size-incompatible'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to use model.predict function for a keras NN model but it returns me the 'Matrix size-incompatible'  error everytime. My training, validation and test dataset is based on 10 samples of 31 inputs and 45 targets. I'm trying to make predictions for 4 different input arrays (31 features). Any suggestions?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

npz=np.load('coal_data_mass_train.npz')
train_inputs = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float)
train_targets = npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_mass_validation.npz')
validation_inputs, validation_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

npz = np.load('coal_data_mass_test.npz')
test_inputs, test_targets = npz['inputs'].astype(np.float), npz['targets'].astype(np.int)

input_size = 31
output_size = 45
hidden_layer_size = 3
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear') 
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError','mse'])

batch_size = 10
max_epochs = 20
callback=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)
model.fit(train_inputs, 
          train_targets, 
          batch_size=10, 
          epochs=max_epochs, 
          verbose=2,
          callbacks=[callback],
          validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets)
          )
test_loss= model.evaluate(test_inputs, test_targets)
Output: 2/2 [==============================] - 0s 0s/sample - loss: 0.3248 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3248 - mean_squared_error: 0.3372

input_data=np.loadtxt('inputs_data.csv',delimiter=',')
first_x=input_data[0,:]
second_x=input_data[1,:]
third_x=input_data[2:]
forth_x=input_data[3,:]

first_y=model.predict(first_x, batch_size=1)
print(first_y.shape)

   Output:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-3fc986b65e7b> in <module>
----> 1 first_y=model.predict(first_x, batch_size=1)
      2 print(first_y.shape)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1076           verbose=verbose,
   1077           steps=steps,
-> 1078           callbacks=callbacks)
   1079 
   1080   def reset_metrics(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    361 
    362         # Get outputs.
--> 363         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    364         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    365           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,1], In[1]: [31,3]
     [[{{node sequential_4/dense_12/Relu}}]]
```

train_inputs shape: 31 features and 6 samples;
train_targets shape: 45 features and 6 samples;
first_x shape: 31 features (1 row)

The code for dataset pretreatment:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
data=np.loadtxt('dataset_mass.csv',delimiter=',')
unscaled_inputs=data[:,0:31]
unscaled_targets=data[:,38:83]
scaled_inputs = preprocessing.scale(unscaled_inputs)
scaled_targets=preprocessing.scale(unscaled_targets)
samples_count=scaled_inputs.shape[0]
train_samples_count=int(0.6*samples_count)
validation_samples_count=int(0.2*samples_count)
test_samples_count=samples_count-train_samples_count-validation_samples_count

train_inputs=scaled_inputs[:train_samples_count]
train_targets=scaled_targets[:train_samples_count]

validation_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]
validation_targets=scaled_targets[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]

test_inputs=scaled_inputs[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]
test_targets=scaled_targets[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]

print(np.sum(train_targets), train_samples_count, np.sum(train_targets) / train_samples_count)
print(np.sum(validation_targets), validation_samples_count, np.sum(validation_targets) / validation_samples_count)
print(np.sum(test_targets), test_samples_count, np.sum(test_targets) / test_samples_count)
```

OUT: 
13.960026602768515 6 2.3266711004614193
4.3277928536591395 2 2.1638964268295697
-18.287819456427652 2 -9.143909728213826

```
np.savez('coal_data_mass_train', inputs=train_inputs, targets=train_targets)
np.savez('coal_data_mass_validation', inputs=validation_inputs, targets=validation_targets)
np.savez('coal_data_mass_test', inputs=test_inputs, targets=test_targets)
```

The dataset_mass.CVS file from which I import my data contain 83 columns (some of which I do not use) and 10 rows.

Comment: Could you add the shapes of `train_inputs`, `train_targets`, and `first_x` to your question?

Comment: Anwarvic, it is done!

Comment: Also, could you add the shapes of `validation_inputs`, `validation_targets`, `test_inputs` and `test_targets`?

Comment: My dataset is based on 31 inputs and 45 targets. The number of samples for test are 6 and for validation and test are 2, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out while defining the model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size,input_shape=(31,), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear') 
])
```

Comment: It returns ' Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (31,) but got array with shape (1,)'.

Comment: I've also tried to transpose the matrix by doing: st_x=first_x.transpose() 
and it return me the same error

Comment: Can I know more about the dataset?

Comment: I've updated my post with the code I use for preprocessing the data and with info about my cvs file. Thank you for your interest in helping me!